# c# application running matlab error using cd too many input arguments

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I am looking to run a matlab function from my c# application.

My code is below, which I edited from this link [matlab example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html) from a previous question on here. However the code is not working.

The error message happens on the matlab.Feval line. Although my code looks the same as the example.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

Additional information: Error using cd
Too many input arguements
```

Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create matlab instance
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
        matlab.Visible = 1;

        // change to the directory where the function is located
        matlab.Execute(@"cd G:\Shared\Folder\Matlab\Non Linear");

        // define the output
        object result = null;

        // call the matlab function upload_data
        //matlab.Feval("upload_data", 0, out result);
        matlab.Feval("upload_data_test", 1, out result, "DMS", "dsfd", 0);
        //[success] = upload_data_test(data_base, str_dir, b_return_data)

        // quit matlab
        matlab.Quit();
        releaseObject(matlab);            

        // display result
        object[] res = result as object[];

        Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I would guess that matlab doesn't like the space in Non Linear. Try going to a different path without the space to see if that works. If so, you make need to somehow escape the space or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
matlab.Execute(@"cd 'G:\Shared\Folder\Matlab\Non Linear'");
```

Note the `'` character to enclose a matlab string.

Otherwise the whitespace character in the path split the input and `cd` thinks it is receiving 2 inputs.